# duplicate symbol arch X86_64

Tags: c++, arrays, qt

I'm writing a code but when building I do have an issue due to a duplicate symbol in main.o and mtp_wrapper.o. The duplicate symbol is _file_extension_type. I'm coding in C++ and Qt

the file_extension_type is an array of struct defined in the mtp_wrapper.h as below:typedef

```
struct {
    char *file_extension;
    LIBMTP_filetype_t file_type;
} MTP_file_extension;


MTP_file_extension file_extension_type [] = {
    {"wav", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_WAV},
    {"mp3", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_MP3},
    {"wma", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_WMA},
    {"ogg", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_OGG},
    {"mp4", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_MP4},
    {"wmv", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_WMV},
    {"avi", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_AVI},
    {"mpeg", LIBMTP_FILETYPE_MPEG}}
```

and this is the only place in which the value us displayed.

mtp_wrapper.cpp contain all my class definition and include by default the mtp_wrapper.h

main.cpp is also including the mtp_wrapper.h but I need it the instantiate my class in the main such as below:

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

....

    // Detecting puls device
    //mtp_wrapper MyMtpPuls;
    mtp_wrapper *MyMtpPuls = new mtp_wrapper;
    error = MyMtpPuls->ConnectPulsDevice();

    ....
```

I guess it coming to the fact I'm including mtp_wrapper.h in mtp_wrapper.cpp and main.cpp..

but if I try to add in the public class the definition of the array such as :

```
Class xxx : yyy {

public:
    MTP_file_extension file_extension_type [];
```

The issue disappear but I couldn't use the function sizeof.

in the mtp_wrapper.cpp I need to know the number element contained in the file_Extension_type and the best way was to divide sizeof(file_extension_type) by sizeof(MTP_file_extension)

but as soon as I declare the array in the class sizeof is unusable.

Any idea ???

I have seen many topics in the duplicate purpose but none of them really fix my issue.

Answer (score 1):

The following defines an instance of a struct, you then try to use the name as a type:

```
struct {
    char *file_extension;
    LIBMTP_filetype_t file_type;
} MTP_file_extension;
```

If you intend that to be a type, place the name right after `struct` instead.

```
struct MTP_file_extension {
    char *file_extension;
    LIBMTP_filetype_t file_type;
};
```

Comment: Thanks I change it but it still failing